# webdriver removing Parameters after Hash Mark (#) in URL

Tags: typescript, google-chrome, safari, cucumber, webdriver-io

I'm adding some UI test using webdriver io, cucumber and typescript and need to include a URL fragment after a Hash mark (#).
This is intended to prevent some modals to be drawn in the webpage,
Right now if I try to do it manually in browsers (Chrome and Safari) it works fine and site behaves as expected. This means, the URL always shows the fragment and modals are never shown. But, when this is done through automated tests, page loads with the fragment after hash, but then it gets refreshed and parameter disappears. This causes modals to appear breaking automation stuff.
Does anyone know a mechanism to make sure page includes this? or if there's any kind of limitation from Webdriver.io side (I'm using v 6.x)?

For example:
(Expected scenario):

1. I open the following URL from my test and it keeps as it is (allowing to some third parties to perform what they have to): [www.my-page.com#something](http://www.my-page.com#something)

(Current scenario):

1. I open the same url than previous scenario but then it gets refreshed leaving it without the parameter. As for example: [www.my-page.com](http://www.my-page.com)

I have tried by escaping the #, setting it in different places or even reloading page. But nothing worked.

**Sadly I cannot share implementation code**

Comment: Could you be be confusing URL query parameters (prefixed with a '?') with the URL fragment identifier (prefixed with a '#').   Fragment identifiers are generally stripped off client-side as part of URI resolution, and the server operates on absolute URIs, which include query parameters, but lack the fragment..   After the resource is retrieved, the client can then use the fragment identifier to select some location within the returned resource, e.g. a web browser can use it to scroll to a particular part of a web age.

Comment: Thus the example you provide of 'www.my-page.com#key=value' seems suspicious.   Can you try 'www.my-page.com?key=value'

Comment: hey @Burt_Harris you're right. I confused naming. I'm referring to URL Fragment. I updated the description already

Comment: @Burt_Harris so you mean that browser will automatically remove this URL fragment from URL once page loads?

Comment: I'm commenting that using a fragment containing an equals sign (=) is, in my experience, unusual and that suggests you may be trying to use the hash (#) for something that it is not intended for. Fragments in a URI are generally a single identifier within a target document. My statement is based on general web experience, not knowledge of the specific technologies you mention. Sorry I can't help further.